# Edit Newly Added Lock Time in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gnome, 20.04, power-management, lock-screen

Several new time period for Power Saving's Blank Screen option has been added via the terminal, such as by running the command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 3600
```

How can we remove some of these newly added time periods, or reset the list of times to the default list?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to work with most `gsettings` values is with the `dconf-editor` GUI. This makes it possible to more easily set, reset, and discover the various settings that are available to you.

If you do not already have it installed, open a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install dconf-editor
```

When you open the application, you can then use the search button to locate all of the power-saving options available, notes on how they work, and the ability to set/reset the values